# Assumptions not working with Trianglewave or Floor functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

The assumption below:

```
Simplify[Integrate[Sin[2 n π x], {x, 0, 1}], Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
```

simplifies the integration and gives $0$ as the correct answer. However, for other functions like TriangleWave[x] or Floor[x], assumptions do not appear to work (Linux, Version 10.0).

None of the commands below simplifies:

```
Simplify[Integrate[TriangleWave[n x]^2, {x, 0, 1},   Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]]
Simplify[Integrate[TriangleWave[n x]^2, {x, 0, 1}],  Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
Simplify[Integrate[Floor[x], {x, 0, n}],  Assumptions -> {n ∈ Integers, n > 0}]
```

I have to use command like:

```
Table[Integrate[TriangleWave[n x]^2, {x, 0, 1}], {n, 1, 5, 1}]
```

to generate a list of result, and "extract" the formula $f(n)$ by observation. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Moo I was answering a question on math.stackexchange.com where I use TriangleWave as sine function in Fourier series :-)

Answer (score 2):

Although it does not help in these particular cases, it is generally better to use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) as in `Assuming[{assumptions}, Simplify[Integrate[ ... ]]]` since the `assumptions` then will be used in both the `Integrate` and `Simplify` steps.

A **workaround** since Mathematica only solves the integrals for specific values of `n` is to generate a sequence for sequential values of `n` and then use [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to find the closed-form expression for general `n`.

```
FindSequenceFunction[
 Table[
  Integrate[
   TriangleWave[n x]^2,
   {x, 0, 1}],
  {n, 10}],
 n]

(*  1/3  *)

FindSequenceFunction[
 Table[
  Integrate[
   Floor[x],
   {x, 0, n}],
  {n, 10}],
 n]

(*  1/2 (-1 + n) n  *)
```

Comment: I almost feel that the very existence of this function (which is new to me) is to handle the problem I had. Also thanks for clarifying the use of assumption.